# mod_wsgi showing old code

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm running mod_wsgi on apache2. It's running Django and for some reason, after I change my code, old versions are sometimes shown along with new code.

For example, after creating a view that simply returns an Http Response with "Hi", I get either the Django start page or "Hi".

Any ideas what would cause this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apache2/mod_wsgi keeps parts of the application loaded between requests. You have to restart the server after code updates.

Comment: In particular read 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode'. Use daemon mode in preference to embedded mode and touch the WSGI script file after changes so code will be reloaded for whole application.

Comment: Thanks! This is the first time I use mod_wsgi instead of mod_python.

Comment: @Temuz, Grzegorz Biały's is much better and should probably be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

As @aaronasterling said - mod_wsgi keeps code loaded however there is no need to restart apache after change. More convenient way is to touch wsgi file from CLI, e.g.:

```
$ touch django.wsgi
```

Comment: +1 but this does only work if mod_wsgi is running in daemon mode

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be your browser caching responses from the server. Try disabling caching to see if that has any affect. Even if it doesn't now, doing so can potentially save you a lot of grief and confusion in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Delete any `.pyc` files from your code base directory, and restart the server.

Comment: I've never had to delete the `.pyc` files because python checks for changes in the source code.